# rails paginate ajax/jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm following Railscast 240: http://railscasts.com/episodes/240-search-sort-paginate-with-ajax

.getScript() seems to be calling but nothing changes whatsoever. Any ideas on why? I'm looking at the request in Network and it seems to be asking for the proper thing.

```
Request URL:http://localhost:3000/user?page=2&_=1312237300119
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using JQuery or Prototype? Make sure you are using JQuery. Not Prototype which is included with Rails 3.0.x

A second thing: it is

```
$.getScript()
```